# Textbox text tips when textbox is empty

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using Visual Studio C# and making textbox. I would like to make a textbox with text hints when the textbox are empty. If the user can entered any characters, the words will be disapear.

like when I using Google Chrome, it will display a grey word to ask you input website or keyword for Google search.
[image]

Are there any ways to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Can you specify which tech you are using? Is it WinForms, WPF etc...

Comment: Google _cue banner_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example for Winforms.

There are several open source solutions for textboxes with watermark you may also check out.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TextBoxHintExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const string hintText = "SO example for watermark";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            textBox.Text = hintText;
        }

        private void textBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox.Text == hintText)
            {
                textBox.Text = "";
                textBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }

        private void textBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox.Text))
            {
                textBox.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
                textBox.Text = hintText;
            }
        }

        private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox.Text != hintText)
            {
                textBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use the `SendMessage` Win32 API to add a hint to the TextBox control.

**Limitations:**

1. Does not work with multiline TextBox controls.
2. Does not support custom font and forecolor.

   ```
   const int EM_SETCUEBANNER = 5377;

   [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet= CharSet.Auto)]
   extern static IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lParam);

   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       SendMessage(textBox1.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, new IntPtr(0), "Placeholder");
   }
   ```

[image]

Comment: this works perfectly and its easy to implement, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard html input `placeholder` attribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#placeholder

It's not clear from the question what technology you are using, but `Windows.Forms.TextBox` also has a `PlaceholderText` property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.placeholdertext?view=windowsdesktop-7.0